# EQCSS + Masonry js not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

Do you have any idea how to make EQCSS working with Masonry? When I setup a different width of item for specific element width then masonry gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a link you can share with us or an example of the code you're trying to use that's broken?

EQCSS applies styles based on element-level breakpoints, and Masonry tries to make a layout from the elements it sees on the page. I don't see why these two should conflict, so I wonder if there's a way we can make them cooperate a little better.

You should be able to find help with EQCSS in the chat room too, try asking there as well: https://gitter.im/eqcss/eqcss